# how to update XML data from java

Tags: java, xml

I want to change the text content of some field in xml using java.  I used setTextContent() for this, but the xml file is not getting updated. 
here is my java code:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
  DisclosureTranslation dt=new DisclosureTranslation();
  String filepath="E:\\Repository\\17Nov_demo\\file.xml";
  dt.getHashmap(filepath);
}
  public void getHashmap(String filepath){


      try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentbuilderfactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentbuilder =documentbuilderfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc=documentbuilder.parse(filepath);
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            Element element=doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList nodelist=(NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/DOCUMENT/ishobject/ishfields/ishfield[@name='FHPIDISCLOSURELEVEL']",
                    doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println(nodelist.item(0).getTextContent());

            String val=nodelist.item(0).getTextContent();
            //String val="111";

            HashMap<String, String> hashmap=new HashMap<String,String>();
            hashmap.put("47406819852170807613486806879990", "public");
            hashmap.put("222"," HP Internal");

            String value=hashmap.get(val);

            nodelist.item(0).setTextContent(value);
            System.out.println(nodelist.item(0).getTextContent());


            }
```

the last line is displaying what i want. But its not getting reflected in the xml file. How am i suppose to update my xml file?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save dom Document in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325178/how-to-save-dom-document-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have updated the element from parsing the xml from the file path, update them to the same file using below method.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult streamResult =  new StreamResult(new File(filePath));
transformer.transform(source, streamResult);
```

Saving the xml back to the file can also be achieved by using **"Transformer API".**